# DatePickerDialog con formato YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, android

Tengo un DatePickerDialog en cual intento poner el mess en formato MM actual me lo pone en M.
E mirado un monton en el foro , e probado poner if con <10 intentando agregar 0+ en caso que es menor de 10, pero no lo consigo.
Me podeis ayudas?
Gracias.

```
 if (v == btnDatePicker2) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                txtDate2.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La mejor forma sería crear un formato de fecha para que se muestre como quieres:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
         new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //aqui defines el formato de fecha que deseas
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
                    txtDate2.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: me pone MM pero da igual que fech eligo , me pone la fecha de hoy

Comment: Edite la respuesta lo puedes ver

Comment: Gracias, Pero tengo otra problema. No reconoce day_of_month y month

Comment: lo siento era `dayOfMonth` y `monthOfYear`

Comment: Solucionado, e cambiado por dayofmonth y va

Comment: Tienes mi voto , jeje Gracias

Comment: jaja ok muchas gracias